# How to get easy access to iCloud in zsh?

Tags: macos, icloud, command-line

I have a new MacBook and did the following in Zsh:

```
% cd  
% mkdir Cloud   
% cd Cloud  
% ln -s /Users/jdoe/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs iCloud
```

I was cautioned "Do not create links to anywhere under `Users/jdoe/Library/Mobile Documents`.

In the same `$HOME/Cloud` dir, I plan also to create links to OneDrive and GoogleDrive. This structure makes logical sense to me.

How do experienced macOS users arrange their cloud directories in Zsh for easy access? For ex, I don't want anything in those cloud drives to end up in TimeMachine. thank you.

Comment: It’s impossible to know why the Apple support person said what they said, but there’s no technical reason preventing you for symlnking `Mobile Documents` as you did.  Usually for me, when someone doesn’t want to explain their reasoning, it’s because they don’t really know

Comment: The symlink works for me, and the "do not create links" comment actually doesn't make sense (you create a symlink *to* iCloud, not within). Why did you reach out to Apple Support in the first place?

Comment: @nohillside My new MacBook includes AppleCare+. To test its limits I discussed cloud drives on macOS to get my feet underneath me asap in a phone conversation. I've got data archives in OneDrive, GoogleDrive, iCloud that need to be unified and then stored in iCloud. There're too many dir and files scattered across these 3 drives to use browsers or Finder. I'm getting access from Zsh, but thinking "why is iCloud hidden like this? Since everyone must access their cloud drives from Zsh, I'll just use the solution of macOS experts."